# Cassandra and MySql integration: How to deal with UUID keys?

Tags: mysql, cassandra

I'm developing a service that is heavily using Cassandra for clustered inserts and queries with over 60 column families.

Up until now, I was able to get around a lot of my problems by re-ordering my keys or adding duplicate (non-normalized) tables with different sets of indexes in order to achieve very fast inserts and queries, but now, I've come across two scenarios Cassandra can't handle out of the box:

1. Text searches across text columns
2. Ordering by counter columns in real-time (See [What data structure should I use to mimic "order by counter" in Cassandra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28498210/what-data-structure-should-i-use-to-mimic-order-by-counter-in-cassandra))

Both these problems have "solutions" but they involve using different engines on top of my Cassandra clusters which are not easy to setup and I have no expertise in using them. Additionally, for my use-case, they look to be a bit of an overkill.

For this reason, I decided that for the few scenarios that require either text searches or certain ordering and paging, I would use MySQL, meaning I would insert the data simultaneously into MySQL and Cassandra for a couple of tables. For normal queries not needing searches or specialized paging, I would use Cassandra but when I needed to do those, I would refer back to MySQL.

It's easy to do this in principle but the problem is, my composite keys in Cassandra are all in UUID format (be that a generated UUID or a time UUID). MySQL however doesn't bode well with UUID as primary OR indexed key from what I've read. (For example, see http://kccoder.com/mysql/uuid-vs-int-insert-performance/).

My question is, how would you recommend dealing with this problem? How can I make Cassandra and MySQL "share" a key whilst maintaining a decent enough performance?

Should I use an auto-increment index on the MySQL and then store that key back into Cassandra so that the next time I need to get the row from MySQL, I query Cassandra for that UUID first and then get the auto increment key out to use in MySQL? Do you have another, better recommendation? Is there anyway to avoid this round-trip?

Please let me know if the question is not clear enough and I'll do my best to explain it further.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

UUID is actually a 128-bit integer, you can use 2 64-bit int in MySQL to represent that.